# set time out not running the function depending on the time

Tags: knockout.js

and I am using settimeout to run the function, every 10 seconds till, it reaches 60 seconds and exits, for some reason it does not go through set time out and just exits the process.

```
self.startInstatorCheck = function() {
  self.instatorStarts(true);
  var MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS = 1 * 60 * 1000;
  var POST_INTERVAL_MS = 10 * 1000;
  var timeout = Date.now() + MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS;

  self.proceedInstantorcheck(POST_INTERVAL_MS, timeout);
}

self.proceedInstantorcheck = function(POST_INTERVAL_MS, timeout) {
  debugger;
  var date = Date.now();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/check_instantor_field/' + auth,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })
    .done(function(userinfo) {
      if (userinfo.instantor_request > 12) {
        return self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Instantor data gathered');
      } else {
        if (date < timeout) {
          /* setTimeout just moves forward and does not repeat*/
          setTimeout(self.proceedInstantorcheck(), POST_INTERVAL_MS);
        } else {
          self.allInstantorCheckMessages('Please go through instantor to ');
          self.instatorStarts(true);
          self.magicInstantorbtn2(true);
        }
      }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
    })
    .always(function(data) {

    });
}
```

I am using two functions since the first one gets the data, and the second one reruns without getting new timeout value everytime.

Comment: I've noticed you've asked the same question three times now, each time deleting the previous version. If you can't figure out the details, comment on the existing answers. If the question is, in your opinion, different from the previous ones, you shouldn't delete the old questions. They could help people with a similar problem and help us understand your case. Also, since many people (including me) have taken the time to write detailed answers, it's kind of rude to just delete everything without a thank you, upvote or "accept".

Comment: @user3297291 Yea sorry about that, I was kinda suffering with this question for so long, and wasnt getting a proper answer, so I was searching here and there for the past 2 days, so did that, yea I understand I shouldnt have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't correctly use `setTimeout`. Its first parameter is a `function`. If this function needs parameters, you'll have to pass them using `.bind` or by wrapping in another method. Here's a working example (note that I've mocked the ajax part and decreased the interval and timeout times).

Notes:

- Press <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see it work.
- This code does not protect you from running multiple `startCheck`s at once. Make sure you only call it once!
- The mocked ajax code has a fixed timeout of 500ms, the `proceedCheck` is therefore called every 1000ms (`POST_INTERVAL_MS`) + 500ms = **1500ms**. Since we stop retrying after 6000ms, we get 5 tries in:

  - Try 1: 0ms,
  - Try 2: 500ms,
  - Try 3: 2000ms,
  - Try 4: 3500ms,
  - Try 5: 5000ms
  - <del>Try 6: 6500ms</del>

```js
// Mock jQuery ajax, do not include 
var $ = {
  ajax: function(opts) {
    return {
      done: function(cb) {
        setTimeout(cb.bind(null, {
          "instantor_request": 10
        }), 500);
      }
    };
  }
}, i = 0;

// The logic:
var startCheck = function() {
  var MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS = 1 * 6 * 1000;
  var POST_INTERVAL_MS = 1 * 1000;
  var timeout = Date.now() + MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS;

  proceedCheck(POST_INTERVAL_MS, timeout);
};

var proceedCheck = function(interval, limit) {
  console.log("Check " + i++);
  $.ajax({})
    .done(function(userinfo) {
      if (userinfo.instantor_request > 12) {
        console.log("Valid request");
      } else {
        if (Date.now() < limit) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            proceedCheck(interval, limit);
          }, interval);
        } else {
          console.log("Request timed out");
        }
      }
    })
}

startCheck();
```

Comment: Hey! I am trying to put the codes together, and thanks for the help, but couldnt understand what instantor request : 10 is ?
I am not getting how to put the var $ = { } with my codes, could you help me out?

Comment: You have to remove the `$ = {}` entirely. I included it because I don't really make a request, but want to imitate the behavior.

Comment: yup I did it, and fiannly it works!!! Thanks alot!!!!!!!!!!!!
Sorry for the trouble yesterday, I was really frustrated!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` takes a pointer to a function, it should not be being passed the result of calling that function.

This

```
setTimeout(self.proceedInstantorcheck(), POST_INTERVAL_MS);
```

should be

```
setTimeout(self.proceedInstantorcheck, POST_INTERVAL_MS);
```

Comment: If you want to provide the two parameters, wrap it in an (anonymous) function: `setTimeout(function() { self.proceedInstantorcheck(POST_INTERVAL_MS, timeout); }, POST_INTERVAL_MS)`

Comment: @Jamiec , I tried it, it still does not call the proceedInstantorcheck, it just skips over it, while debuggin.

Comment: @Farhana wait, are you expecting when you hit the `setTimeout` for execution to stop until that has executed? If so you are misunderstanding what `setTimeout` does.